# How to remove HTML entities from JSON?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, angularjs

I'm creating [a simple RSS feed app using AngularJS](http://jsfiddle.net/02o21rr6/1/) based on [this JSON data](http://rachelbaker.me/wp-json/posts).

I managed to get the post `title` and the post `content`.

But, I got problem when dealing with the `content` data. I want to strip out all the HTML entities inside it and make it looks something like Pocket app like this:

[image]

I just want:

1. Plain text content (in same paragraph structure from the feed source)
2. Center aligned image(s)
3. Hyperlinks
4. Unordered and ordered list items
5. Videos (as result of `embed` tags - if any)

I read about ngSanitize but I couldn't really understand how to use it to achieve what I want.

How to do it?

Comment: just decode the json

Comment: if you want to strip all the html tags from the content then create a regex expression like this str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ' ') and parse Content... you will get plain text as output.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you want to remove the <p> tags but still keep the paragraph structure, which tags exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: You'll want to preserve those html tags if you want to keep the paragraph structure et. al.  Try [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and use css to format for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to completely remove html tags from Json content ...
then check this .... data taken from your sample Json..

Input:

```
var json = {
    "content": "<p>One of the many new features in <a title=\"WordPress 3.5\" href=\"http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.5\">WordPress 3.5</a> is the Iris color picker. <a title=\"Replace Farbtastic color picker\" href=\"http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21206\"> Iris replaces the, now deprecated, Farbtastic</a> color picker script.  The new Iris color picker is shown off in the Theme Customizer for the Twenty-Twelve theme.</p>\n<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-1634\" src=\"http://rachelbaker.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/WordPress-theme-customizer-color-picker2.png\" alt=\"\" /></p>\n<p>As soon as I saw Iris, I fell in love. She is user-friendly, colorful and fun. I found that implementing the new color picker is <a title=\"Adding Farbtastic to WordPress Widgets\" href=\"http://pippinsplugins.com/adding-the-farbtastic-color-picker-to-your-wordpress-widgets/\">very similar to Farbtastic</a>.</p>\n<h3>Iris Color Picker Demo Plugin</h3>\n<p>To use the Iris color picker in a plugin requires:</p>\n<ol>\n<li>Running a version of WordPress that is 3.5 Beta or higher.</li>\n<li>Loading the &#8216;wp-color-picker&#8217; script and style into your plugin options page.</li>\n<li>Adding a text input for your color value to your plugin options page.</li>\n<li>Writing a custom jQuery script to call Iris&#8217;s wpColorPicker method on your color text input field(s).</li>\n</ol>\n<p><strong>How does the code look for implementing steps 2-4?</strong><br />\nI created a demonstration plugin to help answer that. The plugin doesn&#8217;t do anything itself, it is only intended as a guide for developers interested in using the new Iris color picker in a WordPress plugin.</p>\n<p><a class=\"button\" href=\"https://github.com/rachelbaker/iris-color-picker-demo\">View on Github</a></p>\n<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-1635\" src=\"http://rachelbaker.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/screenshot-iris-color-picker-demo.jpeg\" alt=\"Iris Color Picker Demo Plugin\" /></p>\n"
};
var someString = 
json.content.replace(/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi, '').
replace(/&#[0-9]+;t/gi,"").replace(/\[/g,"").replace(/\]/g,""); 


console.log(someString);
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks better. http://jsfiddle.net/02o21rr6/2/ But, how to 

1. maintain the paragraph structure
2. remove "[" and "]" symbols
3. convert doesn&#8217;t  to doesn't
4. keep images?

Comment: your 1,2,3 conditions i have cleared .... check my code i have edited it............... 4 condition is little bit complicated  have to create a conditional regex expression in order to skip img tags...